# Angular query param with parenthesis?

Tags: angular, url, parameters, routes

I have a simple Angular app that uses a query param from the router as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: DefaultComponent
},
{
  path: ':uname',
  component: ProductDisplayComponent
}];
```

This works great and I can access the 'product' "uname" as follows:

```
let prodId = params.get('uname')
```

The issue is that some of the "uname" values are numbers and some are numbers with brackets, for example "567(B)"

Everything works fine if the "uname" is just a number, but once the parenthesis are in the uname the app just redirects to "/".

Is there anyway to get the value when the "unmae" has parenthesis?

Thank you,

Comment: You would need to URL-encode/decode the value for `uname` in order to pass parenthesis through the querystring

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I don't think I should need to encode here as it is just parenthesis (and there are lots of urls with parenthesis I think) Plus, this would be difficult in my usecase anyway. Also, if I move these values to a query parameter (after a ?) It works, I would just rather not do that if possible.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can only use parenthesis as part of a query `?` or `#`, but not in a path segment.

Comment: Suppose you have a url as follows:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752574(v=vs.85)

Comment: Well, as I often do, I stand corrected, however Angular's router may not process that the same as IIS, or whatever is serving that Microsoft URL.

Comment: Thanks Brandon.
Looks like this might be a known issue:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10280

Comment: Looks like the solution is just to escape the parenthesis for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following report: github.com/angular/angular/issues/10280, this is how I solved my issue as originally posted.

1. Create a new class as follows:

   ```
   import { UrlSerializer, UrlTree, UrlSegment, DefaultUrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';

    export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {

        private dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer();

      parse(url: any): UrlTree {
           url = url.replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29');
           return this.dus.parse(url)
      }

      serialize(tree: UrlTree): any {
        return this.dus.serialize(tree).replace(/%28/g, '(').replace(/%29/g, ')');
      }
    }
   ```
2. in "app.modules.ts" (or whatever you modules file is) add the following to providers:

   ```
    providers: [MyOtherServices,  { provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer }],
   ```

   more...

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Because parentheses have a special meaning, I've done a little bit of extra processing, but I'll give you a little example that HOPEFULLY makes sense

```
   {
      path: 'd', component: DComponent,
      children:[
        {path: 'c', component: CComponent},
        {path: 'a', component: AComponent,outlet:'right'},

      ]
    },
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/d/(c//right:a)')
```

It is mainly used as a secondary route outlet

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I follow. I need to get the string "537(B)" in a single component. Can I do this using child routes?

Comment: This is just routing. If you want to pass specific parameters, you can get them in data  
```ts
{
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to retrieve the parameters and I don't think this is the same thing.